# How is "signed or unsigned type" meant in this C90 undefined behaviour definition?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c89

In the ANSI C90 standard, section 6.3 has this to say about expressions:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue that has one of the following types: [...] a type that is the **signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the declared type** of the object

And there is this instance of undefined behaviour in Annex G.2:

> The behavior in the following circumstances is undefined: [...] An object has its stored value accessed by an lvalue that does not have one of the following types: the declared type of the object, a qualified version of the declared type of the object, **the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the declared type** of the object, the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the declared type of the object, an aggregate or union type that (recursively) includes one of the aforementioned types among its members, or a character type (6.3).

I find the wording of the emphasised parts ambiguous and am struggling to interpret it.

1. Does it mean "the signed type corresponding to the original type if it was signed, or the unsigned type corresponding to the original type if it was unsigned"; or "the type (whether signed or unsigned doesn't matter) corresponding to the original type"? That is, is:

   ```c
   signed int a = -10;
   unsigned int b = *((unsigned int *) a);
   ```

   ...undefined?
2. If signed/unsigned doesn't matter, given that the standard makes the distinction between the three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`, would accessing a `char` via `signed char *` or `unsigned char *` be defined?

Answer (score 4):

It's saying that it's *not* undefined behavior to cast the value to a different signedness. If the object is declared `signed int`, you can access it using an `unsigned int` lvalue, and vice versa.

The case where the signedness is the same is already covered when it says "the declared type of the object", although this case could also be considered to say that.

In the case of `char`, both `signed char` and `unsigned char` are "the signed or unsigned type corresponding to" that type.

All together it's just saying that the signedness of the lvalue doesn't affect whether the access is well-defined.

Comment: My comment about `char` being a distinct type was a little vague. I understand that for any given implementation, `char` will either be the `signed` or `unsigned` version; but the standard does go to some lengths to make the distinction in way it doesn't do for the other integral types eg. in 6.1.2.5 there's *"The **three types** `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are collectively called the character types."* I don't know whether this has any real significance though; it sounds like it doesn't.

Comment: `char` is a distinct type. C 2018 6.7.2 5 specifies the elements in each line in the list in paragraph 2 designates the same type, except it is implementation defined whether, for bit-fields, `int` is the same type as `signed int` or `unsigned int`. That list puts `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` in separate lines. Note 45 informs us, in part, “char is a separate type from the other two and is not compatible with either.” Apple clang-1000.11.45.5 reports, when attempting to return either a `signed char *` or an `unsigned char *` for a `char *`, that they are incompatible (both).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, I've edited the answer to say that in this case they both fall into the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that Annex G is informative and the relevant part to quote is normative C90 6.3.

This refers to the precursor to the "strict aliasing rule" later introduced in C99. In C90, it was ambiguous what to do with objects that had no type, such as the data pointed at by the return from `malloc`.

1. It means that if the type of the object is either `signed int` or `unsigned int`, you can do a lvalue access either with `signed int*` or `unsigned int*`. These two pointer types are allowed to alias. So for example if you have a function like this:

   ```
   void func (signed int* a, unsigned int* b)
   ```

   then the compiler cannot assume that `a` and `b` point to different objects.

   (Note that wildly exotic systems can in theory have padding bits and trap representations for signed types, so accessing an `unsigned int` through a `signed int*` could be UB for other reasons, in theory.)
2. The character types are a special case compared to other integer types indeed. But it doesn't matter here, since the rule have a special case too: "or a character type". `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are all character types. This means that all pointer access to an lvalue using any of these 3 types are well-defined.

   The lvalue type doesn't even need to be a character type! You can for example lvalue access an `int` through `signed char*` and it is well-defined, but not the other way around.

Comment: In C89/C90, every object had a type.  Under C89/C90 rules, given `void *vp=calloc(4,128); float *fp = vp; int32_t *ip=vp;`, assuming the `malloc` succeeds, `fp[0]`, `f[]1]`, etc. will be an objects of type `float` and `ip[0]`, `ip[1]`, etc. will be objects of type `int`, while `vp` wouldn't identify any object at all.  The primary problems with C89 were that said "accessed by" rather than "aliased by".  With that change, even though `fp[0]` and `ip[0]` exist simultaneously, and an access to `fp[0]` would access the stored value of `ip[0]`, that wouldn't matter unless code used both...

Comment: ...`ip[0]` and `fp[0]` to access the object, and at least one of those accesses was a write.

Comment: Good point about 6.3, I've made that the primary source in my Q.

Comment: @supercat I'd read it a bit stricter, unless there's another section that informs this? ie. code could have both `fp` and `ip` declared, but only code that does *at most one of* `fp[n]` or `ip[n]` is valid (write or not). Is that interpretation wrong?

Comment: @detly: The C89 Committee was chartered to describe a *pre-existing* language; the behavior of accessing `fp[1]` and `ip[2]` was unambiguously defined in that language when `int32_t` was defined as a type that was the same size as `float`; nothing in the published Rationale indicates any intention to change it.  Committees have generally taken the view that in cases where an action was  unanimously supported and obviously useful, they didn't need to worry about whether the Standard's rules actually defined the behavior or left it as one of the "popular extensions" alluded to in the Rationale.

Comment: @detly: If one interprets the phrase "object" used in the Effective Type Rule as being applicable to the blob of memory returned by `malloc`, even though the definition of `malloc()` does not refer to that blob as an "object", and even though that would be inconsistent with the use of the term elsewhere in the Standard, then writing `fp[1]` and `ip[2]` in that order might leave the "object" returned from `malloc()` with an effective type of `int`, and I think some compiler writers think that's what the Standard intends, but...

Comment: ...that would gut the semantics of the language, be totally contrary to pre-existing practices, and require using the word "object" in a sense that is contrary to its meaning everywhere else.  While the footnote to the Effective Type rule would suggest that "object" should have a novel meaning, nothing in the standard really indicates what that meaning is.

Answer (score 1):

When C89 was written, unsigned types were a sufficiently new addition to the language that a lot of code used `int` in places where `unsigned`--once it existed--would have made more sense.  The authors of the Standard wanted to ensure that functions that used the newer `unsigned` type would be able to exchange data with those that had been written to use `int` because `unsigned` hadn't existed yet.

The Standard is a bit ambiguous as to whether a type like `unsigned*` has a "corresponding signed type" `int*`, or `unsigned**` has a "corresponding unsigned type" `int**`, etc.  Given the purpose of allowing interaction between code that predates unsigned types with code that uses them, making a function that's written to operate on sequences of `int*` unusable by clients that have sequence of `unsigned*` would be contrary to that purpose and also to the Committee's charter.  Upholding the stated purpose wouldn't require that `int**` be universally usable to access objects of type `unsigned*`, but would require that compilers given constructs like:

```
unsigned *foo[10];
actOnIntPtrs((int**)foo, 10);
```

recognize that the called function might affect objects of type `unsigned*` stored in `foo`.